# Drupal 9 giving error after php change, please give a lead on where to start

Tags: drupal

drupal admin suggested php upgrade, so I did. 7.4>8 and now its throwing this error at me. where do I start please ? can you give a lead.

```
Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
Original
ReflectionException: Class "Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\ExceptionTestSiteSubscriber" does not exist in ReflectionClass->__construct() (line 30 of /home/sailbudd/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterEventSubscribersPass.php).

ReflectionClass->__construct() (Line: 30)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterEventSubscribersPass->process() (Line: 94)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() (Line: 762)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1322)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 926)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 20)
Drupal\Core\Installer\InstallerKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 476)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 426)
install_begin_request() (Line: 116)
install_drupal() (Line: 48)
Additional
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "theme.manager". in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition() (line 1030 of /home/sailbudd/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php).

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition() (Line: 600)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet() (Line: 558)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() (Line: 649)
Drupal::theme() (Line: 22)
_drupal_maintenance_theme() (Line: 506)
drupal_maintenance_theme() (Line: 1025)
install_display_output() (Line: 271)
_drupal_log_error() (Line: 365)
_drupal_exception_handler()
```

changed from php 7.4 to 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the 'theme.manager' sevice is no longer available.

Strangely, this service exist and is a part of drupal core since the early versions of drupal 8 and is not deprecated.

You can check it here:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/services/9.4.x

You should start by clearing the cache, since services/routes needs cache clean to work on most cases.

If that do not works for you, check the drupal version and update it to the lastest (and more compatible with PHP8) version.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal

If the error persist, check your custom module directory and search for any EventSubscriber on it. You can also check the custom module .services.yml files where the services are injected.

Answer (score 0):

Our problem was related to the fact, that `composer update -W` removed the `composer/installers` package.

So doing this resolved our issue

```
composer require composer/installers
drush cr
```